# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') when fetching Data using async / await syntax

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-router-dom, dynamic-url

I am trying to access specific data from my django backend based on using the unique id in the url for my react app on the frontend. I expect to see the body of the journal

Instead i get this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

I tried to use, 'useParams' instead but it lead to more errors. I also found similar questions on SO but they mentioned using 'props', is this the method i should be attempting instead?

edit: [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) is an example of why i am using element instead of component.

my App.js

```
import {
  BrowserRouter, Routes,
  Route, Router,
} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header'
import JournalDashboard from './pages/JournalDashboard'
import JournalPage from './pages/JournalPage'

function App() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Header /> 
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" exact element={<JournalDashboard/>}></Route> 
              <Route path="/journals/:id" element={<JournalPage/>} ></Route> 
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

my JournalPage.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

 
const JournalPage = ({ match }) => {


    let  journalId  = match.params.id
    let [journal, setJournal] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        getJournal()
    }, [journalId])

    let getJournal = async () => {
        let response = await fetch(`/api/journals/${journalId}/`)
        let data = await response.json()
        setJournal(data)
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>{journal?.body}</p>
      </div>
    )
}

export default JournalPage
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 there are no longer any route props, so you ***must*** use the React hooks to access these values. To access the match params you can use the `useMatch` or `useParams` hooks.

[useParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams)

For the given route: `<Route path="/journals/:id" element={<JournalPage/>} />` to access the `id` match param, use the `useParams` hook in `JournalPage`.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const JournalPage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams(); // <-- access id match param here
  const [journal, setJournal] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getJournal = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/journals/${id}/`); // <-- passed to API URL
      const data = await response.json();
      setJournal(data);
    }

    getJournal();
  }, [id]); // <-- used as dependency

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{journal?.body}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route path="/journals/:id" element={<JournalPage/>} ></Route>
```

I'm not finding a documentation using `element` prop. Try to use `render` prop instead or with `component={JournalPage}`.

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview this shows an example of using element. I did take your advice and changed that line to component, I no longer get the inital error but now the page loads but still does not show the data and i get this message in the browser console: Matched leaf route at location "/journals/2" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.  Do you have an idea what i could do? @AntoninRiche